# jackson customize Date/ZonedDateTime serializer with dynamic timezone in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson, timezone

I am developing a web system with springboot. It required if the request specifies a time zone, I need to convert the time to the corresponding time zone based on it and return it in the pattern of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Then I tried to use `HandlerInterceptor` and `ThreadLocal` to do it, but I don't know when and where to call `ThreadLocal.remove()`.

**Here is my code for `LocalDateTime`:**

```
public class DynamicZoneIdDateTimeSerializer extends LocalDateTimeSerializer {

    public static class ZoneIdContext {

        /**
         * will set by filter, but when and where I can remove it
         */
        private static final ThreadLocal<ZoneId> zoneIdThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

        public static ZoneId get() {
            return zoneIdThreadLocal.get();
        }

        /**
         * will be invoked in filter or other place
         */
        public static void set(ZoneId zoneId) {
            zoneIdThreadLocal.set(zoneId);
        }

        /**
         * when and where I can invoke it
         */
        public static void remove() {
            zoneIdThreadLocal.remove();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator g, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        super.serialize(convert(value), g, provider);
    }

    /**
     * not convert if ZoneId is null or not set
     */
    private LocalDateTime convert(LocalDateTime value) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneIdContext.get();
        if (zoneId == null) {
            return value;
        }
        return value.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).withZoneSameLocal(zoneId).toLocalDateTime();
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator g, SerializerProvider provider, TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException {
        super.serializeWithType(convert(value), g, provider, typeSer);
    }
}
```

I know that `ThreadLocal` should maintain the principle of who sets it and who removes it, but if it is removed in the `HandlerInterceptor`, then the time zone cannot be obtained during serialization, and if the removal is not called, it may cause unexpected problems.